# New laravel 4 installation on Cloud9, showing blank page when viewing /public folder

Tags: php, laravel, cloud9-ide

I've installed Laravel 4 on Cloud9 (www.c9.io) and I can access a view directly like so:

https://laravel-test-c9-anthonyhull.c9.io/tasks/app/views/hello.php (which displays a "you've arrived" message)

However, if I try to view:

https://laravel-test-c9-anthonyhull.c9.io/tasks/public

I just see a blank page.

I have ensured the following:

- MCrypt is installed
- app/storage permissions have been given write access
- I've tried running php artisan serve

Not sure what else to try.

Ideally what I'm after is to get:

to automatically show the default page of my "tasks" app.

Comment: Looks like I just had to visit https://laravel-test-c9-anthonyhull.c9.io/tasks/public/ directly rather than with the built in Cloud9 IDE browser. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just had to visit laravel-test-c9-anthonyhull.c9.io/tasks/public directly rather than with the built in Cloud9 IDE browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your web server assumingly apache and it's mod_rewrite module which must be installer and enabled. If you do this now, remember to reboot your server, then you also need to change the conf files of apache to allowoverrides and reboot.

Comment: Looks like I just had to visit laravel-test-c9-anthonyhull.c9.io/tasks/public directly rather than with the built in Cloud9 IDE browser.

Comment: you shouldn't need to add "/public" the domain should point to it